# Replacing $n!$ with Stirling's approximation in $e^x = \sum_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, summation, power-series

I was wondering if there is a closed-form expression for

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{e^{-n}n^n},$$

although I expect there is none because Mathematica cannot compute it. However, from Stirling's approximation

$$n! \approx e^{-n} n^n$$

I would expect this sum to be $\approx e^x$ and, in particular, convergent everywhere.

Comment: It definitely converges everywhere (this follows from $ex$ being a fixed number while $n$ grows...that is, $\frac{ex}{n}<1$ for large enough $n$, and at that point, you could approximate using a geometric series).

Comment: As $x \to \infty$ you should get $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}= 1+o(1/x^2),\log f(x) = x+C+o(1/x), f(x) = A e^x (1+o(1/x))$